# How to implement "binding" for coloured petri net in Java?

Tags: java, binding, finite-automata, geometric-arc, petri-net

I'm implementing a [coloured petri net](http://folk.uio.no/andersmo/petrinet/papers/cpn/brief.pdf) in Java. It's kind of a finite state automata. The problem is that I don't know how to implement "binding". In other words, colors should be assigned to places and arc expressions should be assigned to arcs. After a transition is executed, a net should go into a new state. So, I have no idea how to assign functions to arcs.
I hope my question is clear, because I don't want to explain basics of coloured petri nets here. I appreciate if someone could provide a web-link to sample Java code of a colored petri net or give some ideas how to assign functions to arcs.

Comment: Are you looking to use run-time reflection to determine the functions? Or truly anonymous "lambda" functions? Or store an index in an array of pre-determined function references?

Comment: For instance, arc A1 has a function F1, something like: function F1(int x,int y) { return (x+y) }. Here, the values for x and y should be taken from places that are connected to a transition with a given arc. But functions might be much more complicated. Well, if I decide to use an array 'arrayF' with predefined function references, then how can I store these functions? I.e. arrayF[1] = ?

Comment: To continue your example, I was thinking of the table of static functions to be `F1`, `F2`, `F3`, `F4`, .., `F109`, etc. It's more a question of how dynamic are the functions? Are they added / extended at runtime? Or do you know them all when you compile the project?

Comment: I know all the functions when I compile the project. But, of course, the values of input variables of functions change during the execution of a coloured petri net.

Comment: So, could you please give an example how to create an array of static functions and then how to reference these functions? Maybe, this will help to solve my problem. Thx.

Comment: I'd love to but my Java-fu is weak -- I asked for clarification because I thought the question could use the clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Could you please give an example how to create an array of static functions and then how to reference these functions?

The article [*Enumerated Functions*](https://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/enumerated-functions) shows one approach.